# Rails NoMethodError on .save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran the code `@transaction = Transaction.new` Then I gave it some values:

```
<Transaction id: nil, debit_uri: "d8hmFJ89CIQUZMBoiPMnvWkQJW/bank_...", credit_uri: "d8hmciqLOg9bCIQUZMBoiPMnvWkQJW/cards...", seller_id: 2, buyer_id: 6, product_id: 31, price: #<BigDecimal:b4a6115c,'0.45E2',9(36)>, ship_price: #<BigDecimal:b4a61094,'0.123E3',9(36)>, ship_method: "fedex", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

but when I do `@transaction.save!` bang(!) or not I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass
from /home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/validations.rb:194:in `valid?'
```

so I don't know where to look for the error being how my model has little to nothing and there is no method called clear.

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :buyer_id, :credit_uri, :debit_uri, :price, :product_id, :seller_id, :ship_method, :ship_price
  require 'balanced'  
  attr_reader :errors
end
```

Comment: Oh it's just a payment api. Error still happens if I comment that out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Regarding to Rails codebase, the error comes from:

```
attr_reader :errors
```

Look [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L194). Try to remove it from your model.

**Why?**

Since you override the `errors` attributes and did not set it when creating your transaction instance, Rails is trying to do:

```
nil.clear
```

Comment: Wow I definitely would have spent HOURS looking for this if I didn't see your answer. Thanks!!